# how to solve five degree polynomial equation and find unknow python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to solve 5 degree polynomial equation for calculating uknowns. here in this equaion a=0 a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 are unknow need to calculate and x is column value of dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[10,10,9,9,9,8]})

Equation need to solve 
d =  a0 + a1.x + a2.x^2 + a3.x^3 + a4.x^4 + a5.x^5
```

here 'a' is slope parameter

Answer (score 0):

Will drop a handly link to sympy here.
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.